# How do I get all timestamps associated with an ID and aggregate it them into total time elapsed?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a sample table:

```
id   timestamp 
1    2020-02-03T19:25:41.961Z   
1    2020-02-03T19:25:42.000Z   
1    2020-02-03T19:26:33.147Z   
2    2020-02-03T20:21:29.684Z
2    2020-02-03T20:21:29.705Z
```

In BigQuery, I want to group all of the columns with the same ID together, and then get the total elapsed time between all of the `timestamp` cols for that ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `timestamp_diff()`:

```
select id, timestamp_diff(max(timestamp), min(timestamp), second) as diff_seconds
from t
group by id;
```